# Can I pass a USB certificate's password programmatically in .NET?

Tags: c#, certificate, signing

I'm starting to work on a project where the core idea is to use a local .NET Core server to digitally sign data that is sent to it, and then redirect it to the appropriate service out in the web.

The certificate is stored on a USB and I'm using the SafeNet driver to access it and it prompts me for the password each time I do a request that requires signing. I'd like to be able to pass the password in the X509Certificate2, which would be configured in some file so that it doesn't prompt me.

Is this possible? From what I've been searching, I haven't found any way to avoid the prompt and pass the password to the certificate programmatically.
Is there any other driver or token type that would make this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Information from a security token with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137816/how-to-get-information-from-a-security-token-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I think that it helped! I might've found a way to do the trick, just waiting on the PIN from the clients to test it out. Thanks a lot! Will add an answer if it really worked with the generic solution I created.

Comment: Since you said .NET Core, is it a web application with USB Token connected to user's device and user using the application through browser..? If yes, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885